# log on ubuntu server by putty, access denied

Tags: putty

I failed to log on my server via putty today (access denied error) but it work fine yesterday. I checked the passwd of my account and both the accout name and passwd work fine on the server but cannot log on from my windows 7 system via putty. I don't know what's wrong with the putty or the server. I checked nobody log on the server and it just cannot work overnight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide more information. Is this an SSH connection? a telnet connection? Are you limiting access to specific ports? You mention the user/pass work fine on the server, I assume that means when physically in front of the server? You mention you cannot connect from the win7 machine... do you have an error, or where/how does it fail? (times out, etc.)

Common items to perhaps check (and a complete stab in the dark given the limited details)
- Check if the same access works locally from the system. so for example if an ssh connection, from the server itself, try ssh localhost and see if you can authenticate. If you can, then the issue may be between your win7 machine and the server (being blocked, etc.). If it fails, then perhaps the relevant service is not running, or something has changed (listening on a different port, etc.). 
- Verify how you are connecting. Are you using FQDN or IP? If FQDN, verify that your Win7 machine can still resolve the IP address (use nslookup). If it cannot, try connecting via IP address.

The above may help, but really need more details to have a better idea of what may be failing.

Comment: yes, it's ssh. my account and passwd work fine when physically in front of the server but cannot log on when use ssh from putty or from other linux system using ssh.

Comment: ssh localhost is all right